# Splash screen jumps on iPad on iOS 7 + Phonegap

Tags: ipad, cordova, ios7, splash-screen

I'm developing an app using Sencha touch 2 and Phonegap for iOS. The splash screen works fine on both iPhone and iPad on iOS 5 and 6, and on iPhone on iOS 7, but it shifts horizontally (from left to right on about 5-10px) on iPad on iOS 7.

During the experiments I found out it uses 2 files for splash screens: at first it takes the one for iOS 7, and after that the file for iOS 6 and 5. As these files have different sizes, the splash screen shifts when files are changed.

Is there any way to fix it? I have all files set up and with correct sizes: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding "Portrait" and "Landscape" splash screens for iPad with iOS 5 or earlier:

[image]

Comment: Didn't solve it for me. Care to mention what the dimensions are of your files? Going thru q-a's I assumed +/- the status bar also meant +/- 20px from the height. Without the Asset Catalog the dimensions given for ios 6 and below are already -20px or -40px in height.

Comment: Nevermind. I had to delete the app from the simulator/ipad, without doing that it would still use old images. I also went into the build/`project`.app directory (right click "Show package contents") and deleted `Launch-*` images, not sure if I had to but iirc those were old, too. Lastly, the panel above is via the third tab/icon on the right, the "Attributes Inspector". You can just click the placeholders for Launch Images to find out the expected dimensions. For whatever reason the app launches with iOS7 LaunchImage first, then the full screen iOS6- LaunchImage (w/o parenthetic note).

Comment: Also you still need the default images in Resources/splash, otherwise phonegap will fail to compile the app.

Answer (score 1):

Your version of Phonegap does not know how to find the iOS 7 launch images, and stumbles onto the iOS 5/6 file.  I solved the problem in Cordova 2.9 by changing the following lines (starting at line 129) in CDVSplashScreen.m from

```
    imageName = @"Default";
}

if (CDV_IsIPhone5()) {
    imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:@"-568h"];
```

to

```
    imageName = @"Default";
}

if(IsAtLeastiOSVersion(@"7.0")) {
    imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:@"-700"];
}

if (CDV_IsIPhone5()) {
    imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:@"-568h"];
```